# How to print a string one character at a time?

Tags: java

I am having trouble printing a string one character at a time in java. I have to input a string and output it one letter per line. My code is as follows

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringToMultiLines 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    String myString;
    int placeInString = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a string.");
    myString = scan.nextLine();

    while(placeInString <= myString.length())
    {
        System.out.println("" + myString.substring(placeInString));
        placeInString ++;


    }
}

}
```

This ouptuts the following'
Please enter a string.
Hello
Hello
ello
llo
lo
o

I have also tried this with no luck

```
System.out.println("" + myString.subsstring(0, placeInString));
```

and

```
 System.out.println("" + myString.subsstring(placeInString, placeInString));
```

Comment: Use a `for-loop` and `String#charAt` (or `String#toCharArray`)

Comment: `while(placeInString <= myString.length())` indexes are zero-based, so their range is `0` till `length - 1`.

Comment: Using Char At worked fine. Thank you. We just started learning about loops this week.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121233/quick-java-string-tostring-printing-one-char-on-each-line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936319/how-to-print-each-character-from-a-string

Answer (score 6):

You could simply use a `for-loop` and `String#charAt` (or `String#toCharArray`)

```
for (int index = 0; index < myString.length(); index++) {
    System.out.println(myString.charAt(index));
}
```

or

```
for (char c : myString.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Have a look at [The `for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and the [`String` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more details

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `charAt`:

```
System.out.println(myString.charAt(placeInString));
```

And remember that indices start from 0, so `myString.length()` is an invalid index. Thus you need

```
while (placeInString < myString.length())
```

instead of

```
while (placeInString <= myString.length())
```